# ip to domain name mapping failing randomly

Tags: ssh, domain-name

`ssh root@my.local.server` fails 9 times out of 10, with reason "ssh: Could not resolve hostname my.local.server: Name or service not known". So it works **sometimes**.

But once I am connected everything works fine.

If I use the IP (192.168.133.22) of the server instead of myserver.local.int it works all the time.

What is wrong with my setup ? I have followed a tutorial to make the mapping and modified /etc/krb5.conf and did commands like sudo net join ads.... to make the mapping, if it can help.

Edit

I edited back /etc/hosts to what it was when it didn't work. Calling dig mylocal.server.int many times gave me :

(this kind of message the first 37 times)

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> mylocal.server.int
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 63976
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mylocal.server.int.        IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
int.            19760   IN  SOA sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2013091100 3600 1800 604800 86400

;; Query time: 22 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 13 12:27:56 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 91
```

The 38th time :

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> mylocal.server.int
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16605
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mylocal.server.int.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mylocal.server.int. 3600    IN  A   192.168.133.22

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 13 12:27:57 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 50
```

Comment: Fix your name resolution.  what happens if you use `dig my.local.server`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have proper DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`

`nameserver IpAddrofLocalDnsServer`

Or

You can make entry in `/etc/hosts`

```
192.168.133.22 my.local.server
```

Comment: I tried the second solution (/etc/hosts) and it worked just fine, thanks. Any idea why it worked *randomly* before ?

Comment: you can check that using `dig my.local.server`

Comment: I have edited the question with dig answers, how can I read the info to see why it was failing 37 times and suddenly it started to work the 38th time ?

Comment: if you have setup local dns server i.e `bind` and then first you need to check errors in your logs when it failing , if you see any errors then try resolve them , if you don't understand then post it here and also post your `named.conf` and `zone file` , if there is anything then we can suggest you.